# Visual Studio Code redirect input on debug

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

My application is reading from stdin:

```
var input = process.stdin.read();
```

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio Code to redirect input on debug?

So it is be equal to this command line:

```
node app.js < input.txt
```

This configuration is not working, and debug is not starting.

```
{
  "name": "Launch",
  "type": "node",
  "program": "app.js",
  "stopOnEntry": false,
  "args": [
    "<",
    "input.txt"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Input redirection with '<' is only supported if the command and the arguments are interpreted by a shell. But the launch config from above uses the internal debug console of VS Code which doesn't use a 'shell'.
You can add a 'console' attribute to the launch config with either a value of 'integratedTerminal' or 'externalTerminal'. In this case a shell is used and input or output redirection will work.

Comment: Setting `"console": "integratedTerminal"` while redirecting the standard input throws an error: `Error processing 'configurationDone' request. The handle is invalid.`
**console** property should be set to something like `internalConsole`.

Answer (score 4):

The `args` array is generally for Node.js startup and V8 engine runtime flags.

```
  --no-deprecation
  --throw-deprecation
  --trace-deprecation
  --v8-options
  --max-stack-size=val
  --icu-data-dir=dir

  --enable-ssl2
  --enable-ssl3
```

Type `node --v8-options` at the command line to see the full list of V8 runtime flags.

I'd recommend you start your application with the debug flag from the command line so you can direct it to take `stdin` and then attach the debugger to your running process.

```
> node --debug app.js
Debugger listening on port 5858
```

You can have multiple configurations in your launch.json file. Add or modify one to be your "Attach" debug configuration. For attaching, "address" and "port" must be specified (please note that "address" must be set to "localhost" since remote debugging is not yet supported). Port should be the one that the debug startup process returned above.

[image]

Once your application is running on the port specified, you can change the debug target in the dropdown next to the play/run icon.

[image]

Comment: This seems messy, I prefer the solution given by @AndreWeinland in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't apply to node, but for anyone using GDB to debug a C/C++ application using the integrated console, the `<` doesn't get interpreted by a shell. So the workaround is to let GDB create the shell:

`miDebuggerArgs: "'-ex' 'run < /path/to/input.txt'"`