# Visual Studio Code use input text file on debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to follow the direction from this post

[Visual Studio Code redirect input on debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863807/visual-studio-code-redirect-input-on-debug)

but when I add the console config to the launch.json file

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

it throws a "Property console is not allowed". and when I debug the program it still waits on input and never reach break point like I would if I start in shell like

```
"./a.out 1 test1.txt"

"./a.out 1 <test1.txt"
```

Full config

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

    {
        "name": "(lldb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        //"program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.out",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
        "args": ["1", "<","test1.txt"],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        //"miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
        //"preLaunchTask": //"build test1"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: "./a.out 1 <test1.txt" .  should be, it gets cut of somehow when I post it in the main article

Comment: Also if someone could show me how to start the cpp program in shell and then attach my lldb debug to it in vscode. That will also work thanks

Comment: After month of research it seems like currently there is no way to do so in Cpp for LLDB debugger. But there is a workaround for Node, as listed in the question .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863807/visual-studio-code-redirect-input-on-debug

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use `GDB` instead of `lldb` but still encountered the same issue. It waited for an input when I typed arguments in the "launch.json" file this way:

```
"args": ["<", "test1.txt"],
```

But it started working properly when I had rewritten it in the following manner:

```
"args": ["<", "${workspaceFolder}/test1.txt"],
```

I think that one should add a parent folder even though the input file is in the workspace folder or simply use the full path.

Comment: you saved my sanity! first time debugging in vscode.. that compatibility with gdb in linux and sending file to standard input.. omg ... i was trying also some recommendation like have external file where you put "r < /path/to/file.txt" and just put it as args to gdb, but it also didn't work (for me) in vscode launch.json... Finally, thank you!!! :D

Comment: @Dalton where are you able to see output, does it works if externalConsole is true

Comment: `"args": ["<", "${workspaceFolder}/test1.txt"]` and `externalConsole: true` not working for mac vscode. Console output: `zsh: no such file or directory: /correct/path/to/my/file/input.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If you use the integrated console, the `<` doesn't get interpreted by a shell. Usually, using `externalConsole: true` fixes the problem since this uses a shell. But if the external console doesn't work on your system for whatever reason and you're forced to use `externalConsole: false`, the workaround is to let GDB create the shell: `miDebuggerArgs: "'-ex' 'run < /path/to/test1.txt'"`

Comment: works just fine for me in integrated console/terminal. what OS are you on?

Comment: IIRC this was on Ubuntu 20.04. This was a while ago though, so I don't remember the exact steps to reproduce this.

Comment: so you can no longer reproduce the behaviour you previously observed with your new setup? if so, what is the behaviour that you now observe?

Comment: I don't remember where I encountered this issue. None of my current configs have that string at this point. Sorry.