# How to debug with VSCode and pipe command

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using VScode and I would like to debug a program that is used with a pipe command.

In the console, I run my program with

```
cat dataset.txt | python my_program.py
```

How can I configure VSCode to pass the `cat` command so I can debug the program correctly?

I suspect I need to edit `launch.json`?

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
},
```

Comment: perhaps this can help —> https://stackoverflow.com/q/36688454/6817835

Comment: How about passing the path to `dataset.txt` to your `my_program.py` and then read the file's content within the program?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Indeed I can change the behaviour of the program - this is actually how I debug the program for the moment. I was hoping to have a quicker way to perform the action with any behaviour modification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60942159/1901067

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744570/1901067

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73798230/1901067

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63252402/1901067

Comment: https://calvh.medium.com/how-to-pass-input-files-to-stdin-in-vscode-cb31cd7740b8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change "console" to "externalTerminal", when you run the program an external terminal window will open.  This window has stdin connected to the keyboard, so if you type or paste content it will be passed to the program until you send or type ctrl-z.  stdout goes to the window.  Debugging and breakpoints work as expected.

Comment: That's quite tedious - is there no way to automate what's piped in?