# vscode, how to launch and debug program that reads from a pipeline?

Tags: linux, debugging, visual-studio-code

I need to debug my program, callfilter, when it's started like this in Visual Studio Code:

```
 zcat file.gz | build/callfilter/callfilter -M 10
```

Is this doable in vscode ? Here's the current launch configuration for it, which can just start it without any pipe input:

```
 "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) callfilter",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/callfilter/callfilter",
            "args": ["-M", "10"],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: add a parameter that will read from a file instead of stdin, and replace stdin with this file handle

Comment: That's a solution to another problem though. Right now the main problem is setting it up to read from a pipe. (I don't have enough disk space to store the decrompressed file for this debugging case)

Comment: create an attach config, start this pipe from a terminal and attach the debugger to the callfilter process, let callfilter wait for a signal when a parameter is set and send the signal through a terminal when the debugger is running

Comment: Take a look at : https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58349227.shtml

Answer (score 1):

It works with filling the `args` to read from pipeline: `"args": ["<", "in.txt"]`

More information in:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_redirect-inputoutput-tofrom-the-debug-target