# How to add user input while debugging C++ on vscode on macOS

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

How does one add user input when debugging on VScode?

I have tried the following

- Edited my launch.json to set `externalConsole : true`
- Tried giving input as a command line argument as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259717/visual-studio-code-use-input-text-file-on-debug)

Irrespective of following step by step the above methods, something was off.

I kept getting a window where I couldn't do anything. The step up / down / in buttons went inactive.

Here in my launch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++-10 - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++-10 build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my tasks.json file

```
{
    "tasks": [

        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-10 build active file",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-std=c++17",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

System details

```
Version: 1.48.1
Commit: 3dd905126b34dcd4de81fa624eb3a8cbe7485f13
Date: 2020-08-19T17:09:41.484Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The resolve is given in a gist [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5079)

> The issue is when VSCode launches the debug adapter, then the debug adapter launches lldb-mi, then lldb-mi launches Terminal. There is a prompt that should appear, but somehow the DebugAdapter is not forwarding this permissions request.

> The work around is to have VS Code launch the terminal once. You can do this by adding and running this tasks in your `tasks.json`:

```
{
  "label": "Open Terminal",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\"\ndo script \"echo hello\"\nend tell'",
  "problemMatcher": []
}
```

> You can run this specific task using Command + Shift + p. Type Tasks and look for Tasks: Run Tasks then select Open Terminal.

I have written a small blog post about the same, detailing each and every step with images which can be found [here](https://dev.to/nullpointerx00/debugging-c-in-macos-10hi).