# How do I run a program in VS Code and use a text file for input? i.e. the equivalent of 'myprogram.exe < inputfile.txt'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a program and want to test it with a large amount of inputs that have saved in a text file. Is there a way I can do this within VS code?
I have already tried modifying launch.json to this:

```
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args" : [ "< C:\\file\\path\\testcase.txt"]
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:
I have changed to:

```
   "args" : [ "<", "${workspaceFolder}/testcase.txt"]
```

but it still isn't receiving input from the file.

Comment: [Visual Studio Code use input text file on debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63252402)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp My launch.json already has the console tag. I rearranged the args array as shown there but the program still waits for input instead of receiving it from the file.