# F# with VS Code : Redirecting user input

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#

I use Visual Studio Code 1.37.1, OS Windows 10. I  have installed F# with Ionide.

How can I launch the code to redirect user input to a file as I would do with Visual Studio 2019 ("< in.txt" in CommandLineArgs Option of the debugger).
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

It is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863807/visual-studio-code-redirect-input-on-debug) and not F# specific.
In launch.json

```
{
    "name": "someName",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/someName.dll",
    "args": ["<", "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/file.txt"],
    "console": "internalConsole",
}
```

works with internalConsole for me.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that doesn't work.for me. Perhaps I should learn how to use correctly VS Code before !!I

Comment: @joel76 - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863807/visual-studio-code-redirect-input-on-debug - apparently you need to make the `console` parameter be something other than `internalConsole`. I've seen `integratedTerminal` and `externalTerminal` suggested. Do either of those work?